# Want to open WebView in each list item click?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, listview

I Want to open a static HTML file in each click of List item but when i call my listview is disappeared . please help me to short out this problem.
My Tab1Fragment.java Code is this

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,  
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab1, container, false);

    Resources res = getResources();
    mainTopic = res.getStringArray(R.array.MainTopic);
    mainDescription = res.getStringArray(R.array.DescriptionContent);
    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), mainTopic, image1,                
 mainDescription);
        listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);


        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        wb=(WebView)view.findViewById(R.id.webView);
                        wb.loadUrl("file:///assets/ActivePassive.html");
                        wb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                        wb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
                }
            }
        });

        return view;


    }
}
```

My fragment_tab1.xml code is :-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="androidthirst.company.abhi.totalenglish.Tab1Fragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

And my separate listView code is this
single_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#1A237E"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_margin="9dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:id="@+id/imageView" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"

        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView" />
    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webView">

    </WebView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

[Here you can see the image i just want to open thml file in first list Item Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9nEi.png)

Comment: Help anyone please

Comment: Explain "when I call" and what exactly is disappearing. Maybe add a screeenshot of the problem

Comment: Thanks for your reply i am adding screenshot

Comment: *Try* to change 'wb.loadUrl("file:///assets/ActivePassive.html");' to
 'webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/ActivePassive.html");'

Comment: It's not working sir

Answer (score 1):

Try Bellow code:

```
list_Id.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                        int position, long id) {
                    list_Id.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                                int position, long id) {
                            WebView webView = new WebView(v.getContext());
                            String[] urls = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.bookmark_urls);
                            webView.loadUrl(urls[position]);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

Create a file `string-array.xml` inside `values` and put all web addresses as bellow:

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="bookmark_urls">
        <item>http://www.google.com</item>
        <item>http://www.android.com/</item>
        <item>http://www.facebook.com/</item>
        <item>http://www.android.com/</item>
        <item>http://www.android.com/</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Comment: Please don't add the [same answer to multiple questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/is-it-acceptable-to-ad??d-a-duplicate-answer-to-several-questions). Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates, once you earn enough reputation. If it is not a duplicate, tailor the post to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your layout is "fragment_tab1"

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab1, container, false);
```

While you wrot layout name "My **tab1_fragment.xml** code is :-"

please check is that exact layout?

And your Webview is in Row file which used in adapter class.. (single_row.xml)
You tried to load in activity..

Thanks abhi..

Comment: ok abhi, your webview is in adapter class layout...single_row.xml, It should be in fragment_tab1

Comment: t should be in fragment_tab1

Comment: I was put it in fragment_tab1 also but it's not worked out.

Comment: Will you check design ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like below

```
  String url = "http://www.example.com";
  Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
  i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
  startActivity(i);
```